# Android: CheckBox not checked on ItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-checkbox

I want to check a checkbox when grid item is clicked in a fragment and I did this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    context = container.getContext();

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ac_image_grid, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;

    Cursor imagecursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            columns,
            null,
            null,
            orderBy);

    this.imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < imagecursor.getCount(); i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        imageUrls.add(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));

    }

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
        .cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .build();

    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(context, imageUrls);

    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);     
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "helo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            CheckBox itemCheck = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            itemCheck.setChecked(true);

        }
    });
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
}

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_multiphoto_item, null);
        }

        CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        final ImageView imageView =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imageLoader.displayImage("file://"+imageUrls.get(position), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
                imageView.setAnimation(anim);
                anim.start();
            }
        });

        mCheckBox.setTag(position);
        mCheckBox.setChecked(msparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);

        return convertView;
    }
```

But this code either toasted nor checked the checkbox with it.. I am not getting that what is the problem...

My **ac_image_grid.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMulMsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/uploadMsg"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnViewImg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMulMsg"
        android:columnWidth="100dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="4dip"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="18dip"
         >
    </GridView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/btnBg"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/btnSelect" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and **row_multiphoto_item** is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgDesc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is your item layout?

Comment: @tasomaniac I have edited my code above please have a look